# Translation problems for some elements

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, localisation

I use an MG 2.3.4 installation and add the splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de component to apply German as used language for the frontend. It works. I also use a simple custom skin, based on Luna.

Now I add a de_DE.csv file in the i18n folder of my skin and change some translation with success:

```
Shipping, Verpackung und Versand,,
```

The default translation for `Excl. Tax` is not good, and I try to change the translation in the same way without any success. I add these strings:

```
(Excl. Tax),(Zzgl. MwSt.)
"Excl. Tax","Zzgl. MwSt."
Excluding Tax,Zzgl. MwSt.
```

deploy and flush cache. No change:

[image: Translation for tax]

I also did a full-text search an all installed file, and I found only the component above. I have no further ideas :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
rm pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/js-translation.json
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE -f
```

Comment: ```rm pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US``` 
solves the problem without any further translation change. I suppose the default quick-deploy strategy is not secure enough to find all necessary updates.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a cache problem.
Flush your magento cache, open a new private browser and check again.

Comment: As written, I flush the cache on every try (server-side). I try it additional now with a private session of my local browser without success.

Comment: Then just look for how it's translated in the DE csv. I'm almost sure that it's translated with a specific Module Name like Sales or Catalog. just copy the whole Line into your i18n Folder, that'll be enough..